# Is it possible to run Pylint on the last commit changed lines and not on the all file?

Tags: python, git, pylint

Is there a way or a flag that I can use to run Pylint only on the changes of the file from the last commit? (only the changed lines and not all the file)

Answer (score 0):

Not directly with pylint, [darker](https://pypi.org/project/darker/#using-linters) is a project that does this for various tools, including pylint (I'm not using it myself).